# Wordpress_logged_in cookie not destroyed on logout

Tags: wordpress, cookies, authentication, wordpress-login

Users get stuck in a login/out loop experience - ONLY on the /login screen.

I have a membership plugin activated (Restrict Content Pro) that utilizes a login shortcode which I'm using on a /login page. I have a global login/out link, utilizing wp_logout_url(); for logging out.

Behavior works as expected everywhere on the site except the login page. If I logout then return to the login page, I'm shown content as if I were logged in. If I attempt to logout from this page I'm thrown to the "You are attempting to log out of 'x'. Are you sure you want to do this?" error page.

The cookie 'wordpress_logged_in_' is also present only on this page. So, I'm under the impression this is why the site is displaying the 'logged-in content'. My question is - why would this specific cookie only be saved on this specific page? Can I completely destroy it on a log out?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

This issue seems to be persistent till date. Are there any updates on solutions for this? Seems to me that WP is not destroying all the cookies relevant to login. After investigating a little I found that the login cookie was set for a particular path(in my case it was `/my-account`). Maybe WP is missing this cookie as this is not set to `/`.

Comment: Please provide additional details in your answer. As it's currently written, it's hard to understand your solution.